# Why is "display: table-cell" messing up my div's?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the strings "1","2" and "3" vertically as seen here:

[image]

But when I use `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` for all 3 div's, but then I get his unwanted result:

[image]

HTML is

```
<div id='alldivs'>
    <div id='red' class='each_div'>1</div>
    <div id='blue' class='each_div'>2</div>
    <div id='green' class='each_div'>3</div>

</div>
```

CSS is

```
.each_div { 
     width: 80px;
     height: 50px; 
     text-align: center;
     display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/hAZZE/1/)**

How do I keep the 3 div's aligned vertically while keeping vertical alignment within each div?

Comment: keep the 3 div's aligned vertically while keeping vertical alignment within each div??

Comment: Is each string going to be only a single line?

Comment: Take a look at the answer I just wrote that involves the line-height property; much cleaner I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a conceptual misunderstanding. Without a parent element with `display:table-row` the tables cell will always span over full width, because it will create anonymous table object of `table-row` and `table`.

According to W3C Specification article: **[Tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes)**

> Document languages other than HTML may not contain all the elements in the CSS 2.1 table model. In these cases, the "missing" elements must be assumed in order for the table model to work. Any **table element will automatically generate necessary anonymous table objects around itself**, consisting of at least three nested objects corresponding to a 'table'/'inline-table' element, a 'table-row' element, and a 'table-cell' element. .....

[Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#table) is a quirksmode page showing uses of `display: table` and so on. A image showing the same effect as on this question.

[image]

To solve this problem semantically, you have to add an extra element to display as row.

```
<div id='alldivs'>
    <div id='red' class='each_div'>
        <div class="cell">1</div>
    </div>
    <div id='blue' class='each_div'>
        <div class="cell">2</div>
    </div>
    <div id='green' class='each_div'>
        <div class="cell">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then assign relative CSS to them

```css
#alldivs { display: table; }

.each_div {
     display: table-row;
}

.cell {     
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/hAZZE/3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. In fact, it works even without `display:table` in `alldivs`. Thanks

Comment: @eric01, Read my latest update, whether you define a object with `display:table` or not, an anonymous table object will be created and wrap the element.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a much simpler way, using `line-height`:

```
<div id='alldivs'>
    <div id='red' class='each_div'>1</div>
    <div id='blue' class='each_div'>2</div>
    <div id='green' class='each_div'>3</div>
</div>

.each_div { 
     width: 80px;
     height: 50px; 
     line-height:50px;     // set to the same height as the div
     text-align: center;
     clear:both;}          // add clear both to skip line
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KjZH8/2/) here and compare with the other answers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap each one in another `<div>` with `display: table-row;` and it will look as you wish:

HTML:

```
<div id='alldivs'>
        <div class="row">
            <div id='red' class='each_div'>1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id='blue' class='each_div'>2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id='green' class='each_div'>3</div>
        </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
.each_div { 
     width: 80px;
     height: 50px; 
     display: table-cell; 
     vertical-align: middle;
     border: 1px #000 solid;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}​
```

This is because `table-*` is designed to emulate a table, thus one must follow table structure to get table appearance. In this case you may just want to use a table.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work-around that works the way you want. If you wish then you can use it:

Change your CSS as:

```
.each_div { 
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px; 
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align:center;
     background:red;

}
#alldivs{
    width:80px;
    display:block;
}
```

Note that I have mentioned `width:80px` for the parent div `alldivs`

It gives the output as:

[image: Output of above CSS]

​

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It has partially solved it. The 3 div's are vertically aligned. But the width of the 3 div's is still wrong; it should be 80 px. Is there any way of fixing that? Thanks a lot